# Regex Expression Not Capturing Wanted Data

Tags: regex, expression

Goal: Trying to capture just Invoice # Column values. My goal was to use the Date to the right of the invoice number to capture the invoice number on the left.

Issue:  The formatting of string we are working with has rolled up the last line of the details on to the line before it. See DM20052921
I'm not able to grab (DM20052921) and also getting an unwanted line at the bottom and the top with my regex?

My Regex: ([A-Z\d]+).+(?= 20\d{2}-)

Sample Text:

2020-06-02 PURITY LIFE HEALTH PRODUCTS LP Page 1 A/P Remittance Advice Direct Deposit 2020-06-02

Cheque # 10215 Vendor # 0600 HAIN CELESTIAL CANADA, ULC

**Invoice #** Date Description Gross Disc Net ===================================================================================

**220339**     2020-04-24 P2152762     2,569.44   .00   2,569.44

**221887**     2020-04-29 P2153903     1,655.68   .00   1,655.68

**221967**     2020-04-29 P2153899     3,210.68   .00   3,210.68

**222055**     2020-04-29 P2153904     1,574.09   .00   1,574.09

**CR01BBN0**   2020-05-18 MULTI MCBS   86.65-     .00   86.65-

**CR01BBWG**   2020-05-25 MULTI MCBS   98.02-     .00   98.02-

**CR01BB4I**   2020-06-01 MULTI MCBS   60.37-     .00   60.37-

**DM20051917** 2020-05-13 INVENTORY WRITE OFF 1.44- .00 1.44- **DM20052921** 2020-05-21

INVENTORY WRITE OFF 23.96- .00 23.96- ========================================== 8,739.45 .00 8,739.45

Printed on 2020-06-02 at 13:4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're over thinking this...

```
/([A-Z\d]+)\s\d{4}/              // This works for your example
/([A-Z\d]+)\s\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/  // This double checks it's followed by a date
```

Comment: The second one works well but it captures the date also, so we need to exclude the matched date from the matched string.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it is not capturing all invoices? It does return the 2 on the same line; but I'm trying to capture all invoice numbers.  The first 5 invoices should be 220339, 221887, 221967, 222055, CR01BBN0..... etc.

Comment: @Steven my apologies your suggestion worked. I just had to do a couple tweaks because of some spaces: ([A-Z)\d]+)\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[^a]  The word **on** was also coming in for some reason on the very last line so I added the [^a] to stop this line from being included. Regardless it's fixed thank you. How do we close the question as being answered?

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it helped! You just mark the answer as accepted (which it looks like you've done, thank you)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
([A-Z\d]+)(?=\s\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

Found these things

> 

2020-06-02 PURITY LIFE HEALTH PRODUCTS LP Page 1 A/P Remittance Advice Direct Deposit 2020-06-02

Cheque # 10215 Vendor # 0600 HAIN CELESTIAL CANADA, ULC

Invoice # Date Description Gross Disc Net ===================================================================================

**220339** 2020-04-24 P2152762 2,569.44 .00 2,569.44

**221887** 2020-04-29 P2153903 1,655.68 .00 1,655.68

**221967** 2020-04-29 P2153899 3,210.68 .00 3,210.68

**222055** 2020-04-29 P2153904 1,574.09 .00 1,574.09

**CR01BBN0** 2020-05-18 MULTI MCBS 86.65- .00 86.65-

**CR01BBWG** 2020-05-25 MULTI MCBS 98.02- .00 98.02-

**CR01BB4I** 2020-06-01 MULTI MCBS 60.37- .00 60.37-

**DM20051917** 2020-05-13 INVENTORY WRITE OFF 1.44- .00 1.44- **DM20052921** 2020-05-21

INVENTORY WRITE OFF 23.96- .00 23.96- ========================================== 8,739.45 .00 8,739.45

Printed on 2020-06-02 at 13:4

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it is returning only the 2 invoice numbers on the same line (DM20052921 and DM20052921)  which is good; but, .....it's not picking up the rest of the invoice numbers above it?

Comment: \b([A-Z]+\d+[A-Z]*\d*[A-Z]*)\b

Comment: I assumed your invoice has capital letters and should contain at least one number

Comment: After capturing the group please validate with total characters in that string, I think it should be 8 or 10

Comment: Just tried your suggestion: \b([A-Z]+\d+[A-Z]*\d*[A-Z]*)\b and this is closest I've been so far. I'm trying to capture Invoices from Invoice column. The first 5 invoices should be 220339, 221887, 221967, 222055, CR01BBN0..... etc. The invoice may start with a number or capital letters? Your script is ignoring the invoices that start with a number and accidently grabbing words from Description column with Capitals followed by numbers.  Hope you can figure it out.

Comment: Yeah I thought the invoice will not start with numbers

Comment: Hi David, I think we need to capture the string that is followed up by the date and exclude the matching date. It will give the voice only. Thanks for commenting to focus on that